# Are there any other Java schedulers besides Quartz(FOSS) and Flux(Commercial)

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I am interested in finding out about other job scheduling packages besides Quartz and Flux. Given the plethora of web frameworks i find it peculiar that there is really only one scheduler. Are there others that perhaps are not as well-known or popular?

[**SpringBatch**](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/faq.html#schedulers): Not really a scheduling solution but rather a batch job coordinator etc.

> How does Spring Batch differ from Quartz? Is there a place for them both in a solution?
>
> Spring Batch and Quartz have different goals. Spring Batch provides functionality for
>   processing large volumes of data and Quartz provides functionality for scheduling tasks.
>   So Quartz could complement Spring Batch, but are not excluding technologies. A common
>   combination would be to use Quartz as a trigger for a Spring Batch job using a Cron
>   expression and the Spring Core convenience SchedulerFactoryBean.

Comment: Why? It seems that Quartz got it right so there isn't need for anything else.

Comment: You forgot about TimerTask in the JDK, which I often think could/should be used for simple scheduling tasks (no need for Quartz).

Comment: TimerTask is a bit too simple. It cant handle jvm restarts.

Answer (score 1):

There are others, just not as well known necessarily:

http://java-source.net/open-source/job-schedulers

Also, as I mentioned above, TimerTask can be handy for simple tasks.

But I have to admit Quartz did a great job - it's one of the reasons they were ultimately "bought".  jquery is a similar type of well-known solution when you might think there'd be more than there actually are.

Comment: Actually there are many competitors to JQuery that work in the same way - eg matching DOM nodes, adding listeners, doing stuff etc.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz is nice but just an API. Flux is pretty feature rich but more about workflow than hard-code scheduling. Another job scheduling alternative is JobServer with its open source SDK, soafaces. soafaces is a way to build modular server-side java Tasklets. It has lots of scheduling rules and job reporting/monitoring UI stuff also.